# Replacement for if-is-app-user

Tags: php, facebook, graph, fbml

Now that FBML is depricated, does anyone know the best way of returning a list of friends that are also using the same app.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for old GetAppUsers call to see a user's friends who use my app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/replacement-for-old-getappusers-call-to-see-a-users-friends-who-use-my-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [is-app-user documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.isAppUser/)

```
 Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, and have added 
 equivalent support to the Graph API for this method. Please use the Graph API 
 User object and GET /[UID]?fields=installed to check if a user is has TOSed that app.
```

Also, you already should have the uid of all users of your app, because you have your own state saved, so you could just use that.